# Does Scala's list form a monoid under the concatenation operator?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, monoids

First of all, sorry, but I'm not a native English speaker. I will however try to do my best.

I'm actually studying some theoretical concepts as a hobby to deepen my understandings of functional programming and have some questions to check that I correctly understood what a monoid is.

First of all, the definition of a monoid that I found is that a monoid is a set that is closed under an associative binary operation and has an identity element. I guess it's correct?

So, using the following definition, I suppose that Scala's lists form a monoid under the `:::` operator, as `List` is a set, `:::` is associative `(xs ::: (ys ::: zs) =  (xs ::: ys) ::: zs)` and `List` has a base element (`Nil`). Am I right?

Regarding monoids, is there something to say about the `::` `List` operator? I suppose not as it's not taking two lists as parameters, but an element and a `List`. Am I still right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First of all, the definition of a monoid that I found is that a monoid is a set that is closed under an associative binary operation and has an identity element. I guess it's correct?

As far as I know, that is correct. *(disclaimer: I am still learning too)*.

> So, using the following definition, I suppose that Scala's lists form a monoid under the ::: operator, as List is a set, ::: is associative (xs ::: (ys ::: zs) =  (xs ::: ys) ::: zs) and List has a base element (Nil). Am I right?

Also correct.
For example here is the definition of [`Monoid[List[A]]`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/kernel/src/main/scala/cats/kernel/instances/list.scala#L86) in [**Cats**](https://typelevel.org/cats/) - and here is an specification of the [`Monoid[List[A]]`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Monoid.scala#L10) in [**Scalaz**](https://scalaz.github.io/7/).
Both are *libraries/frameworks* for functional programming in scala, and as you can see they both define the Monoid for List using `:::` and `Nil`.

> Regarding monoids, is there something to say about the :: List operator? I suppose not as it's not taking two lists as parameters, but an element and a List. Am I still right?

Again as far as I know, you're still right.